# Why after render an partial,@users_shown is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In controller, I have `@users_shown`. In views, I render a partial `_attendants.html.haml` with `@users_shown`.

It's okay but there is a button on this page called `attend_again`, while you click this button, it will render the partial via AJAX with partial `_attendants.html.haml`.

The question is in the partial `_attendants.html.haml`, `@users_shown` is `nil`. I don't know why.

file _attendants.html.haml like this

```
- unless @users_shown.blank?
  -@users_shown.each do |user|
    user.name,user.id
```

Comment: can you give more info about it? I would like to see the ajax call for example if possible

Comment: $('#page_attendants').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "xxxx/_page_attendants") %>');

Comment: There's actually no ajax in that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set @users_shown in your controller action that is rendering the ajax _attendants partial.  It's a completely separate request, and needs all relevant data set appropriately.

Comment: hi,thx.this is no ajax _attendants,just _attendants.html.haml

Comment: I realize. The controller that renders attendants.html.erb needs to set @users_shown, despite you setting it with your initial page render. If you can't set it easily, you can put the value in the session, but I wouldn't recommend doing that with any kind of object.

Answer (score 0):

Try add a local to the partial rendering like:

```
<%= render :partial => "xxxx/_page_attendants", :locals => { :users_shown => @users_shown } %>
```